# I have a working React build on a live server, I can not get it to work locally

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm not entirely sure where to begin on this question, so bare with me --
I have the copy of a live version of a React.js build.  I am attempting to set it up locally so I can make changes.
I cannot get it to work.

I have tried the following:
Deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling each module in the package.json file one at a time with the version in the package file.  Doesn't work.
Installing the dependencies and updating them all from an npm install (overarching).

Neither seems to help.

I turned on the debugging stuff that the previous developer put in and everything they are checking for checks out.

I can not make the app behave locally.  I have spent days trying to debug.
It connects to the server. I have XAMPP installed and the folder for the app is in the htdocs folder.
The one error I keep getting (locally, not live) is the "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component." error.

All I want to do is work on this application.  It's about 2 years old, I didn't write it, and the person who did is unavailable.

I know this is a vague question, but I have no idea what to do next.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: that's really hard to answer, since it's 2 years old, a lot libraries can break your application. if you don't have many libraries, you can check out them.

Comment: I'll take a look at the ones being called by CDNs.  At least gives me something I haven't tried. Thank you.